# AddIn for Outlook 2016 on top menu

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

How I can create an AddIn for Outlook 2016 using c# like appears in the image? For example, In this case I see the "LikeForOutlook" addin when I receive a message, and I can respond immediately with a happy face

[image]

my code is empty :(

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Note: Outlook no longer raises this event. If you have code that 
        //    must run when Outlook shuts down, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=506785
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a Web addin (JavaScript) - see https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/outlook-add-ins

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed